The cantillon Effect asumes that money is not nutral right?
I am a austrian high school student and as a part of our final exams we have to write a small scintific paper. I decided to write about the Cantillon Effect and its implications and realised that there were far too few scientific papers on the subject. I am now much deeper into the subject than I would like to be. I am now looking at the neutrality of money and the question has arisen in my mind as to whether the Cantillon effect does not already presuppose that money is not neutral. Since there is a widespread belief that money is neutral in the long run, I ask myself a very fundamental question: does this still make sense?
I would be very grateful if someone could help me!
